# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string - error

Tags: php

I need help understanding this error, just starting out ;)

Could this part of code cause the error in the subject?

```
$var = explode(',', $var);
```

I'm guessing exploding $var would need it's own variable, for example:

```
$myvar = explode(',', $var);
```

I need to understand as the first code did work on my server without warning, but my co-worker is getting the above warning.

Comment: Please show us more code. What does `$var` contain? How do you initialize it?

Comment: As warning says `$var` must be string you must be passing something else than a string in second parameter.

Comment: The problem is that the value of `$var` is not a string (for some reason...).

Comment: Ok maybe I should elaborate on $var. There is a user field where they specify a comma separated list (2,23,24). I need to use that value as an array.

Comment: @user3441665 in that case there is an error somewhere in your code, because the value of `$var` is not the value of your field.

Comment: What are the contents of `$var` on that specific line (`var_dump($var);`)? We are no where near interested in what you EXPECT to be happening.

Comment: The best thing for you will be start from here  http://www.php.net/explode

Comment: You also get the warning message when `$var` is empty

Comment: Thanks for your help so far guys. The problem I am facing is that the user can enter a comma separated list of values, for example `2,14,56`. The information they entered is stored in the database, and I need to use the string they have put in as an array, as the rest of my code goes: `if ( is_open ($var) ) { echo "Welcome"; }`. Without exploding `$var` I only get the first value of the string. However, when exploding `$var` in the way specified above, my co-worker gets the error.

Comment: Did you var dump $var in the line where your co-worker get's the error? what exactly is the error? does it point to this line in your code where you define $var? maybe there is another explode in hte code somewhere? what does is_open do? it is not a default PHP function right?

Comment: Yes. Error is: `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /public_html/app/extention/arrow/functions.php on line 72`. Yes, that's the line where $var is defined. Correct, not a default PHP function, but a built in function of the CMS we are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial concern that you can not overwrite $var with explode(',',$var) is wrong since PHP is able to change the type of $var.
This code adjustment however should lead you closer to where your problem is.

```
<?php

if(!is_string($var)) {
  echo "\n$var contains:";
  var_dump($var);
  die('as you can see, var is not a string');
}
elseif(stripos($var,',') == FALSE) {
  echo "\n$var contains:";
  var_dump($var);
  die('var is a string but has no commas');
}
else {
  $var = explode(',', $var);
  echo "\nnow $var contains:";
  var_dump($var);
  die();
}
```

Also, as mentioned, RTM and check out how [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting "var is a string but has no commas".

Comment: and the output before that? What does $var contain? It should tell you that. See my edit to this post and finally answer the question people asked since the beginning of time: What is the content of $var at the moment where your error occures.

Comment: Sorry, should have done it in my initial comment. `string(4) "1,22" var is a string but has no commas`

Comment: content of $var = 1,22

Comment: Made another edit since my code was wrong. If you have "1,22" as content in $var, your code should not throw an error.
As you said, the error only occures at your co-worker.
So he probably doesn't have "1,22" in his $var if he uses this code right?

Comment: Tried the edit, I don't receive an error. Thank you!!! I'm guessing my co-worker's input is wrong...

Comment: You might consider "accepting" my answer. IT is the polite way to appreciate answers and help here on stackoverflow. It gives you reputation as well and the more reputation you have .. well .. read about it in the FAQ right? Good luck with your learning curve. Maybe drop by this page here. IT helps with getting into the real deal :D http://www.phptherightway.com/